# How to have all threads complete execution after test time is up in JMeter?

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

After a JMeter test ends, I want all remaining threads to complete going through the whole test plan before being killed. This is because the next test run will generate errors, when a thread was killed during execution in the previous run. I do not want all the threads to be killed off at once.

Scenario I am using:
 1. User logs in
 2. User changes password 
 3. User changes back password
 4. User logs out

If a thread is killed during step 2 when JMeter is ending test plan, there will be an error when the user logs in during the next test run. I want the whole flow to be completed by remaining threads when the test is ending.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as of last version of JMeter.

You should open an enhanced request for it.